# Is it OK to share files with Dropbox and other file-sharing services in posts?

Tags: discussion, questions, answers

I encountered [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24943071/2615940) in the first post review queue. The question seems okay to me, but the user attempted to add what appears to be a DropBox link to share the input files he/she is attempting to process. The link is broken, but that's beside the point.

Assuming the link was working, what is the opinion of using DropBox to share files in questions? Certainly code files should be stripped of everything not relevant to the question and embedded in the post, but what about support files that may help answer questions, but aren't part of the code? Is there another, more trusted alternative service we should use?

Comment: I can't imagine what additional info would be necessary to share on dropbox in a good shaped question. Do you?

Comment: @AndrewBarber: Well, a Fiddle is at least useful for testing. But dropbox...

Comment: @juergend Yeah, true enough. So; compared to *other* links, then! pffft

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It is not acceptable, in my opinion, to have to resort to using 3rd-party external services to host files that are needed to answer a question. **Questions themselves should contain everything that is necessary to help solve them.**

If future readers stumble upon the same question, and the link to the file-sharing service becomes broken, the information in that link that was necessary to solve the problem *is not lost*, rendering the question **Answers too should be self-contained**, for the same reason.

If someone expects other users to have to visit an external web page or file hosting service in order to get files that are necessary to solve the problem, I would either edit the necessary resource into the question itself, or I would close the question with the reason:

> Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**.

**Trustworthiness of files hosted on external services**

The other reason why I object to forcing other users to download files is because such files may contain **malware**, either intentionally or unintentionally.

Comment: Malware is my biggest concern. I can see the utility of including links to supporting files, but I can't think of a case when that utility outweighs the risk to the community inherent in third-party links to downloads.

Comment: What should an asker do, if their question is about reading data from a binary file?

Comment: @AndreSilva feel free to post your own answer `;)`

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan if someone asks you to download a file in order to help them read data from a binary file, is that really a good question? First, the question is not self-contained, because it relies on an external, off-site resource. Second, they're not describing the problem in words clearly enough such that it's not necessary to download a file at all.

Comment: @AndreSilva well now I'm curious, what do you consider to be "legitimate exceptions"?

Comment: @Patricia: (sorry for the reply to an old comment, just saw this post)... the likelihood is high, when a question relies on binary data too large to be included in the question itself, that the question author has not sufficiently narrowed the question. Binary data dumps are no more welcome than code dumps in lieu of a good MCVE. And even when it's impossible to reproduce the problem except with a very large binary file, and that file can't be generated programmatically (i.e. with code included in the post), then that would suggest the question is not generally useful enough for SO.

Comment: The only way to avoid using third-party file hosts would be for SO to have it's own, and even that would still not prevent malware.

Comment: @martineau: Having our own hosting would prevent replacement of the contents with malware, by forcing new contents to have a new URL.  Off-site hosting suffers from a problem that a legitimate download can accrue positive reactions, and then all that trust and reputation can be silently transferred to a replacement.