# Should there be an automated message when cloud links are used in questions (Dropbox, Google Drive, etc)?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, asking-questions, external-links

It's been said ([here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266714/is-it-ok-to-share-files-with-dropbox-and-other-file-sharing-services-in-posts) for example) that we shouldn't use personal cloud links like Dropbox, Google Drive, Spideroak, etc to share data files in questions because:

1. They tend to break over time and
2. They represent a non-trivial security risk for those who click them

I see it happening a lot though and I get tired of being the stick in the mud who says "don't do that".

This made me wonder if there should be some sort of automatic warning like there is with jsFiddle links?

Comment: The question and title sounds like you're asking *whether* there should be a message but the [meta-tag:feature-request] tag sounds like you're asking for there to be one.

Comment: @cat That's because someone else added that tag

Comment: @Hack-R if you disagree with an edit, you're always free to revert it. If you're okay with it being a feature request, you should turn the question into that. If it's about discussion, you should probably remove that tag.

Comment: @AndrasDeak To be honest, I don't mind. I originally meant it as discussion because I didn't want to be so pushy as to request a feature without feeling out the community for support first, but if someone else feels it should be a feature request then I am cool with that too.